# Show image only if jsonObj has a value

Tags: php

If `<?php echo $jsonObj->data->image; ?>` has a value, like 1234.jpg I want to show this:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/img/<?php echo $jsonObj->data->image; ?>"  />
```

If `<?php echo $jsonObj->data->image; ?>` has no value, then `<img src="https://www.example.com/img/<?php echo $jsonObj->data->image; ?>"`  /> should remain hidden.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php `if-else` statement for that.

```
<?php
   if(!empty($jsonObj->data->image)) {
?>
     <img src="https://www.example.com/img/<?php echo $jsonObj->data->image; ?>"  />
<?php
   }
?>
```

You can add `else` part and do whatever you want.